# Silently Uninstall specified Software on Machine

Tags: powershell, uninstallation

Currently this is my PowerShell Script that I have written to Uninstall a piece of software from my machine, in this Case it is Zoom.

```
$MyProgram = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq “Zoom”}
$MyProgram.uninstall()
```

For Some reason, I get the following error -
"You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression."
My apologizes as I am still new to PowerShell and learning, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The WMI query returns no results, so `$MyProgram` is `$null` (hence the error).

Comment: `get-package *zoom* | uninstall-package`  Mine is called 'Zoom (64-bit)' and it's an msi install.

Comment: You can also use a filter like this, but only for msi installs, and it takes about 1 min 20 sec `Get-WmiObject Win32_Product -filter 'name = "zoom"'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the answer is "WMI query returned no results", because either the name is wrong or it's not an msi install.

Comment: That makes Sense! I dont believe it was a MSI install, If I recall its an .exe, so that would explain it.

Answer (score 0):

considering zoom is an MSI installer, below snippet can help.

```
$app = Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall, HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall |
            Get-ItemProperty |
                Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -match "Zoom" } |
                    Select-Object -Property DisplayName, UninstallString, Displayversion, PSChildname, PSPath
                    
        $productcode = $app.pschildname
        msiexec /x $productcode /qn
```

Note: Assumed that there is only one zoom application. if there are more more, then $app datatype might change to array and you need to do for each loop